# How to build a particle detector, given a desired probability of detection

Tags: particle-physics, measurements, statistics, particle-detectors

Suppose that the average flux of cosmic rays at sea level on an horizontal surface is $$\varphi = 1\, {\text{cm}}^{-2}\,{\text{min}}^{-1}$$
and that we can take this value without error.

What should be the size of a fully-efficient horizontal square detector at sea level in order to have a probability $\geq 90\%$ to have at least one detection per second?

---

I thought that if we had a square detector of surface $60\,\text{cm}^2$ we should have probability $100\%$ of record an event per second, hence I should have a detector of side $\sqrt{0.9\cdot 60}=\sqrt{54}$ in order to have a probability $\geq 90\%$ to have at least one detection per second.

Is this simple reasoning correct?

Answer (score 4):

A 60 cm$^2$ detector does **not** have a 100% chance of detecting 1 particle within any given second.

Considering that the cosmic ray flux is roughly constant and the probability of hitting a given area does not materially change as a function of location on Earth, we can safely assume that the number of cosmic rays per minute on a given 1 cm$^2$ patch follows **Poisson statistics**, with a mean of 1 particle per minute in that patch. This means that the probability of having $n$ particles in a given minute in the patch is

$$P(n)=\frac{1}{e n!}$$

(because the mean is 1). So you actually have a 37% chance of seeing **zero** particles within a minute, a 37% chance of seeing **one**, an 18% chance of seeing two, and so on.

Likewise, one square cm will see an average of $1/60$ of a particle per second, so the probability of seeing $n$ particles per second is given by

$$P(n)=e^{-1/60}\frac{\frac{1}{60}^n}{n!}=\frac{1}{60^ne^{1/60}n!}$$

which gives you a 98% chance of seeing zero particles per second in one square cm.

Since we know that each square cm of the detector is independent as far as cosmic rays are concerned, the chances you'll see zero particles in a given second are $(e^{-1/60})^{60}\approx 0.37$.

In other words, with a detector area of 60 cm$^2$, you'll have a 37% chance of seeing no particles hit the detector in a given second.